# What is the keyboard shortcut for the mouse right-click functionality on sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, editor, sublimetext, text-editor

I am using the keyboard and then I get to the point I want to open the menu little menu, so I had to open it using right-click on the mouse since I couldn't find the shortcut.

**What is the keyboard shortcut to do "right-click" and open the little menu that pop-up?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are calling the "little menu" is called a "context menu" ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_menu)).

Sublime Text does set a key binding for this but which one depends on your operating system.

```json
// OSX:
{ "keys": ["alt+f2"], "command": "context_menu" },

// Linux and Windows - context_menu is a keyboard key:
{ "keys": ["context_menu"], "command": "context_menu" },
```

For Linux and Windows the expectation is that the keyboard has a special key assigned to opening a context menu, usually this is called the *menu key* and has a menu or document icon printed on it, see this [Google images search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=context%20menu%20key) for example photos.

For the purposes of key bindings Sublime Text refers to the menu key as `context_menu`, this may be slightly confusing because Sublime Text also uses `context_menu` as the command name to open a context menu.

You can of course change the Sublime Text context menu key binding to whatever you want in the usual way. For example to `ctrl+shift+y`, e.g.

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"], "command": "context_menu" },
```

Your screen capture shows a context menu being opened on a file name in the Sublime Text side bar. I do not think this can be done by just using keys, unfortunately I think it requires the mouse. The `"ctrl+0"` keys force the focus to the side bar (the same keys for all OSes) but once that is done pressing the context menu's keys does not open the context menu in the way that you have shown. This is certainly true on Linux (which I use) and probably also true on Windows and OSX. Perhaps users of those OSes could add a comment to confirm whether that is the case or not.

Comment: Indeed, the `context_menu` command only applies to buffers and not to the side bar.